# data from two asynchronous calls to google maps geocoder

Tags: google-maps, asynchronous, google-geocoder

After reading lots of posts here (most of them are unfortunately API v2 related) and still getting no clue, my humble request:

I am trying to get LatLng data from two geocoder calls:

```
                    function geocoderMarkerA(fromValue) {
                        return geocoder.geocode( { 'address': fromValue}, function(results, status) {
                          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map, 
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                icon: 'red_MarkerA.png'
                            });
                            return results[0].geometry.location;
                          } else {
                            Ti.API.info("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                          }

                        });
                    }

                    function geocoderMarkerB(toValue) {
                        return geocoder.geocode( { 'address': toValue}, function(results, status) {
                          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                            var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
                                map: map, 
                                position: results[0].geometry.location,
                                icon: 'green_MarkerB.png'
                            });
                            return results[0].geometry.location;
                          } else {
                            Ti.API.info("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                          }

                        });
                    }
```

I tried using $.when but I still can't get both returned data. I just want to have both results as two variables or an array.
My enormous gratitude in advance!

Comment: What is the error, you are getting ?

Comment: I am not getting an error, the data is undefined

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect two points in Google map..?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773388/how-to-connect-two-points-in-google-map)

Comment: The link you posted does provide the answer. Thank you!